# doubleValue does not convert the object to a double value correctly at all times

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, double

I have an NSArray in which I would like to store double values. I defined it as follow

```
NSMutableArray *setOfDoubles;
```

I add the elements as follow

```
NSNumber *num;
num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:someDouble];
[setOfDoubles addObject:num];
```

And I read the element as follow

```
num = [setOfDoubles lastObject];  
[setOfDoubles removeLastObject];
doubleValueToUse = [num doubleValue];
```

My problem is sometimes (Not always), for example when num (as an object) is 5.1, doubleValueToUse (as a double value) is 5.099999999999996. The way I figured num (as an object) is 5.1 is that I debug and when I am hovering the mouse on top of num on the line  num = [setOfDoubles lastObject]; it shows 5.1 but after doubleValue conversion it becomes the number I mentioned. Does anybody know why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every number can be accurately represented using a float variable. For example, you can't precisely represent, say, 1/3 using a finite number of digits in our common decimal (base-10) system, but in ternary (base-3), it would be just 0.1. Similarly, the numbers you can write with a finite number of digits in decimal, may not necessarily have the finite number of digits in their binary representation, hence the error.

A few links on the topic if you are interested:

http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1108.html

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand what the problem is. So how do calculators, either physical calculators or let say iPhone calculator, go about solving this problem? Do they use a different data type instead of float? Or do they implement some sort of rounding?

Comment: Rounding is definitely used (e.g. try 2/3), and possibly other techniques (say, using fixed-point calculation if possible).

Comment: Thank you! The links you sent helped a lot. I found out that carrying out the manipulations with the precision of float (or double) and then presenting the result with lower number of decimal places by formatting strings (like %g.14) will resolve the issue. I don't know if I am going to encounter exceptions to this, but so far it's working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is normal for `float` values.

If you want to save initial (same) representation of `float` numbers in all places of your code, you can save them, for example, in `NSString`. When you will need float number you will just write `[NSString floatValue];`. But it is not effective if you have large amount of `float` values.